# problems android studio and facebook sdk and gradle version

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have some problem to use the faccebook libraries on android studio. I've follow the guide on  facebook developer web site. however  i'm not able to use the code. 
i've copied all the example but it still give me the exception:

on ...libraries\facebook\build.gradle
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:facebook'.

> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.7

do someone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

open build.gradle in the facebook project and update :
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'

to : 
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

Comment: i've already tried it, but it return: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':FbMapEvent:processDebugManifest'.